# Symfony5 + Nginx + x509 Client Authentication

Tags: symfony, nginx, certificado-ssl, symfony5

Estoy intentando crear una autenticación de cliente mediante certificado x509 en Symfony5 con Nginx:

Este es mi security.yaml:

```
#security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        client_certificate:
            memory:
                users:
                    Q1234567G:
                        roles: ROLE_USER
    firewalls:
        public:
            pattern: ^/public
            anonymous: true
        secured:
            pattern: ^/secured
            x509:
                provider : client_certificate
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/secured, role: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

La idea es validar un certificado con el siguiente formato:

CN=XXXXXXXX,OID.2.5.4.97=VATES-Q1234567G,serialNumber=Q1234567G,OU=XXXXXX,O=XXXXX,L=XXXX,C=XX

Mi nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  gzip  on;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    # HTTPS
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
      # x509
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

    # enable client certificate verification
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
    ssl_verify_depth 3;
    root PATH;
    server_name SERVERNAME;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/symfony/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_I_DN $ssl_client_i_dn;
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    }
    location ~ ^(\/secured)$ { # Don't forget to change here with your own regex
        if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
          return 403;
          break;
        }
      try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
}

}
```

Para ser capaz de comprobar el parámetro "SerialNumber" del certificado hago un override de la clase X509Authenticator con la siguiente clase:

```
namespace App\Security;


use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractPreAuthenticatedAuthenticator;
/**
 * This authenticator authenticates pre-authenticated (by the
 * webserver) X.509 certificates.
 *
 * @author Wouter de Jong <wouter@wouterj.nl>
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * @final
 */
class X509Authenticator extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedAuthenticator
{
    private $userKey;
    private $credentialsKey;

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, string $firewallName, string $userKey = 'SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email', string $credentialsKey = 'SSL_CLIENT_S_DN', LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($userProvider, $tokenStorage, $firewallName, $logger);
        $this->userKey = $userKey;
        $this->credentialsKey = $credentialsKey;
    }

    protected function extractUsername(Request $request): string
    {
        $username = null;
        if ($request->server->has($this->userKey)) {
            $username = $request->server->get($this->userKey);
        } elseif (
            $request->server->has($this->credentialsKey)
            && preg_match('#SerialNumber=(.*?),.*#', $request->server->get($this->credentialsKey), $matches)
        ) {
            $username = $matches[1];
        }

        if (null === $username) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(sprintf('SSL credentials not found: %s, %s', $this->userKey, $this->credentialsKey));
        }

        return $username;
    }
}
```

y creando un servicio en services.yaml:

```
security.authenticator.x509.secured:
    class: App\Security\X509Authenticator
    arguments:
        $userProvider: '@security.user.provider.concrete.client_certificate'
        $firewallName: 'secured'
```

También he creado un TestController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route; #Rutas para PHP8
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;


class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    
    #[Route('/public', name: 'public')]
    public function checkPublicAccess(): Response
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Este es el acceso publico !',
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/secured', name: 'secured')]
    public function checkSecuredAccess(): Response
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Este es el acceso securizado !',
        ]);
    }
}

?>
```

Estoy recibiendo este error cuando intento acceder a /secured:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource.
```

Soy nuevo en Symfony Security y no tengo claro si puedo hacer este oveerride cambiando la expresión regex:

```
preg_match('#SerialNumber=(.*?),.*#', $request->server->get($this->credentialsKey), $matches)
```

También destacar que cuando cambio el parámetro anonymous=false en el security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
        public:
            pattern: ^/public
            anonymous: true
        secured:
            pattern: ^/secured
            anonymous: false
            x509:
                provider : client_certificate
```

el mensaje de error cambia a :

```
A Token was not found in the TokenStorage
```

Muchas gracias, cualquier idea o comentario es bienvenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución al problema. Es viable realizar el override de la clase X509Authenticator, pero es necesario incluir en el fichero security.yaml:

```
#security.yaml
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
```

De este modo se deja de utilizar la clase deprecated X509AuthenticatorListener para usar la clase X509Authenticator y de este modo hacer que el override funcione correctamente.
En esta clase podremos comprobar no solo el campo EmailAddress del certificado sino también, como en mi caso, el campo VATES-